# Использование своего DNS сервера для сайта

Tags: сеть, dns, bind, cname

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста возник такой вопрос, а с администрированием плохо знаком.

Собственно есть зарегистрированный домен например `helloworld.com`, у меня в личном кабинете (регистратора доменов) соответственно можно указывать NS сервера.

Допустим сейчас у меня прописан IP моего сервера, естественно с статическим IP, например `95.111.111.111`. Все мои домены ссылаются на 1 сервер сейчас, с этим же IP.

В настройках прописаны NS сервера регистратора доменов. Например `ns1.godaddy.com` соответственно на данный момент насколько я понимаю в зонном файле данного сервера прописан мой IP и домен.

Вопрос вот в чем, могу ли я установить у себя на этом же сервере (пока что) DNS сервер например `bind9` настроит там простейший зонный файл где будут все поддомены и так далее, все как обычно. И в итоге прописать мой сервер вместо NS сервером хостера.
НО тут у меня вопрос вот в чем. У меня то в личном кабинете есть возможность прописать как и имя (домен) так и IP адрес NS сервера, но во многих случаях я встречал что используется только домен, то есть `ns1.superns.com` например.
Вот тут возникает вопрос, каким образом будет резолвиться мой DNS сервер с доменом `ns1.helloworld.com` если по сути это палка в двух концах, то есть  мой сервер должен резолвить как раз мой домен `helloworld.com`.

Скажите пожалуйста можно ли сделать что-то подобное, или я бред написал.
И еще такой вопрос, что происходит когда мы меняем в настройках акаунта у регистратора NS сервера ? (желательно поподробнее)

Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

День добрый! Да, сделать это можно. Когда вы меняете в ЛК регистратора NS сервера, то регистратор посылает в реестр доменной зоны специальную заявку, в которой будет указано, что отныне домен такой-то обслуживается на сервере таком-то.

Если хотите, можете посмотреть пример, выполнив в Linux'е команду

```
dig ukrnames.com +trace
```

Или зайдите на сайт dig.ua, введите там ukrnames.com, перейдите на вкладку "Команда dig", а затем ниже выберите "dig +trace".

Это как раз реальный пример того, как домен обслуживается на ns-сервере, который является его поддоменом. Называется это - дочерние NS. Вероятнее всего у регистратора есть отдельная форма/страница для их регистрации. Вам нужно будет указать и имя и IP. После этого - в реестр будет послана заявка на регистрацию дочерних NS. Настройте ваш сервер, убедитесь что он отдаёт верные записи (командой `dig @<адрес_вашего_DNS> <ваш_домен> ANY`) и если всё правильно - пошлите вторую заявку, на смену NS для вашего домена. Тут вам уже надо будет указать лишь имя сервера, без IP. Конкретные подробности вы можете уточнить у тех. поддержки вашего регистратора.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Про команду dig знал, а вот вопрос все таки про то если имя самого днс сервера резолвиться им самим же, выходит, что просто регистратор должен внести запись типа А где будет имя сервера и айпишник верно ?

Comment: @Ptzhub, да, регистратор должен его зарегистрировать в реестре - указать его имя и IP.